# ScrollTo directive not working in IE

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have this directive to provide an animated ScrollTo:

```
.directive('scrollOnClick', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, $elm, attrs) {
            var idToScroll = attrs.href;
            $elm.on('click', function(e) {

                var $target;
                if (idToScroll) {
                    $target = $(idToScroll);
                } else {
                    $target = $elm;
                }

                $("body").animate({
                    scrollTop: $target.offset().top
                }, "slow");
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
```

and the HTML is:

```
<li><a href="#section1" scroll-on-click>Learn More</a></li>
```

This works fine in Chrome but in IE 9 or IE 11 there is no response when I click on the links. Any ideas?

Comment: Insead of `$("body")` try with `$("html, body")`

Comment: Thanks - I will give this ago when I next get access to a machine with IE.